# Porting native C++ to .NET

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, porting

I have a set of .cpp and .h files with native c++ code on it. I want to use this code as a dll library in a code written in C#, Visual Studio 2010.

***Could you tell me what is the best way to do this?***

Comment: You might consider C++/CLI.

Comment: You use DLLImport/PInvoke to do this. MSDN has lots of information, as does pinvoke.net.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes, But, you mean that I should translate the C++ code to C++/CLI?

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the DLL code.  Your C# library can import functions from the DLL, regardless of the language the DLL code is written in.

Answer (score 3):

This is a good example taken from [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on `PInvoke`-ing taken from MSDN.

```
// PInvokeTest.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    public static extern int puts(string c);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Test");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

So, a good starting point is to take a look at `Platform Invoke` or simply  `PInvoke`
here is a good tutorial for this

**[`Platform Invoke Tutorial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

or

1. http://manski.net/2012/05/pinvoke-tutorial-basics-part-1/
2. [`Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

Comment: This is awfully close to a link only answer. Could you provide a "sample" pinvoke snippet or something similar to flesh it out a bit?